# Scala - implicit conversion of type to Option[type]

Tags: scala

This seems very odd to me: say I have a variable which is `Option[someType]`, and I assign a `someType` object to it, why do I have to explicitly cast my object to an option?

```
var num: Option[Int] = Option[Int](3) // works
var num: Option[Int] = 3              // seems reasonable, but doesn't compile
```

**Edit:** I meant my question to be more about "why did Scala implement it like this", rather than "how to work around this". As you can see I know how to work around it.

What I'm curious about it the rationale that says that an `Int` can't be thought of as an `Option[Int]`. I get why an `Int` isn't a `List[Int]`, for example (allthough I can also imagine a paradigm is which it is) but I don't see the logic in not making the conversion to `Option[Int]` seamless.

Comment: I think it would be more normal to say `Some(3)`. I don't believe you are casting. I believe you are call `Option.apply(3)` (which returns a `Some(3)`)

Comment: Yes, from a logical perspective it might make sense to say 'all values of type `A` can also be thought of as optional values of type `Option[A]`', but in practice it's it can be very annoying and sometimes very unsafe to have this automatically happening.

Comment: While types under `AnyVal` cannot be null, there's no way for the Scala compiler to statically know than an instance of an `AnyRef` type isn't null.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to cast it. You simply have to create an object of type `Option[Int]`, because `3` is not an `Option[Int]`.

`Option` is a type like all others. Would you expect for instance `val l: List[Int] = 3` to also work?

If you really want it done automatically you can:

```
implicit def anyToOption[A](a: A): Option[A] = Option(a)
```

But implicit conversions from and/or to general types are usually considered bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

An `Option` can have two different states,

Either it is `None`:

```
val num: Option[Int] = None
```

Or it is defined as `Some`:

```
val num: Option[Int] = Some(99)
```

You could define an implicit conversion to convert from `Option[Int] to Int` and vice-versa, but doing implicit conversions on types you don't own is generally frowned upon.

The reason your code doesn't compile is because you are assigning a type of `Int` to something that is expecting `Option[Int]`, and there is no implicit conversion in scope.